# What format and data type is data in the stream.read in pyaudio?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am trying to use pyaudio for a real time audio application. The program that I wrote works, but I am trying to optimize the speed. Additionally, the main issue I have is that I am trying to process the stream.read() data. In the general method for doing this, the data is stored into an array called frames where you just append each chunk to the array. This array is then processed into a .wav file. I want to translate this over into integers or float that have meaning in terms of their digital value but I do not know the conversion to do so. To make this clearer, the code that I use translates the frames array into a .wav file. Then, I use soundfile to translate the .wav file data back into points. These points I then run for frequency processing and it works well.I want to cut out needing to convert to a wav and back from a wav to get usable data. I believe that the data values are in byte format but represent a 16 bit integer, but when I divide by 2^16 I do not get the correct value. Some confirmation on this would be helpful. Here is something similar to what i'm doing without the frequency processing

```
import pyaudio
import wave


filename = "recorded.wav"
chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
channels = 1
sample_rate = 44100
record_seconds = 5


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# open stream object as input & output
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=channels,
                rate=sample_rate,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk)
frames = []
print("Recording...")
for i in range(int(sample_rate / chunk * record_seconds)):
    #what is this value?????????
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)

print("Finished recording.")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(filename, "wb")
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
wf.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Comment: maybe use `print(type(...))` to see what type of data you have, I'm not sure but ith may keep it as `numpy.array`. You can also use `print()` to see what values you have in `frames`

Answer (score 1):

It gets data as bytes string and you can convert it to list of integers using

```
#data = b"".join(frames)
data = b"\x01\x02\x01\x04"   # example data for test

result = []

for index in range(0, len(data), 2):
    value = int.from_bytes(data[index:index+2], 'big')
    result.append(value)
    #print(value)    

print(result)
```

Result

```
[258, 260]
```

I only don't know what order of bytes uses 16bit integer in this string - `big` or `little` (`big-endian` or `little-endian`)

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use standard module [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) for this.

`H` means `16 bit unsigned integer` and `>` means `big-endian`

```
#data = b"".join(frames)
data = b"\x01\x02\x01\x04"

import struct

length = len(data) // 2
result = struct.unpack(f'>{length}H', data)

print(result)
```

or using iterator (so you could run it with every `chunk` instead of using full `data`)

```
result = []

for items in struct.iter_unpack(f'>H', data):
    result.append( items[0] )
    
print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use standard module [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

```
#data = b"".join(frames)
data = b"\x01\x02\x03\x04"
    
import array

#a = array.array('H')
#a.frombytes(data)

a = array.array('H', data)
a.byteswap()  # convert from little-endian to big-endian

print(a.tolist())
```

---

If you use `numpy` then you can use [numpy.frombuffer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html)

```
#data = b"".join(frames)
data = b"\x01\x02\x03\x04"

import numpy as np

arr = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='uint16')

print(arr)
```

but this uses `little-endian` order.

For `big-endian` you can use `dtype='>u2'`

```
arr = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='>u2')
```

or

```
dt = np.dtype('uint16').newbyteorder('>')
arr = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=dt)
```